# How to use table and aggregate in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `tt`. I would like to know how many different types of variants I have for different STATUS using aggregate and table functions. I tried `aggregate(tt$STATUS, by = list(tt$variant), table)` , but it gives me weird column names that I couldn't understand. How do I properly do this?

```
tt <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:11, .Names = c("9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "2280", "2415", "3096", "4095", "6437", "7642"), .Label = c("003-0029-0258443", 
"003-0039-0349951", "003-0041-0357849", "003-0042-0388658", "010-0001-0040921", 
"4_596_8", "5_26202_105", "64368", "A-ADC-AD002860", "MAP_64368", 
"S0085"), class = "factor"), variant = structure(c(`9` = 1L, 
`10` = 1L, `11` = 1L, `12` = 1L, `13` = 1L, `2280` = 2L, `2415` = 2L, 
`3096` = 3L, `4095` = 2L, `6437` = 3L, `7642` = 3L), .Label = c("0/0", 
"0/1", "1/1"), class = "factor"), STATUS = structure(c(`9` = 2L, 
`10` = 2L, `11` = 2L, `12` = 2L, `13` = 2L, `2280` = 1L, `2415` = 1L, 
`3096` = 1L, `4095` = 1L, `6437` = 1L, `7642` = 2L), .Label = c(" 1", 
"-9"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "2280", "2415", "3096", "4095", "6437", 
"7642"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to apply `table`, can use directly after subsetting the columns instead of applying it within `aggregate`

```
table(tt[c("STATUS", "variant")])
#      variant
#STATUS 0/0 0/1 1/1
#     1   0   3   2
#    -9   5   0   1
```